# save button state on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, button, sharedpreferences

I am creating an app with lot of buttons. I programmed the buttons so if I don't click them, the background color stays white and if I click them the background color turns to green. I want to save this green button. so if I close the app and reopen it I want previously turned green buttons to remain green but unfortunately reopening the apps makes the button white. What can I do?

Comment: Use shared preferences

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this with SharedPreferences.
SharedPreferences will store the data that you want.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
prefs.edit().putBoolean("button1", true).apply();
```

This above code for to write your data to SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
boolean isButtonPressed = prefs.getBoolean("button1", false);
```

Above code for read your button value with key ("button1"). default value would be false beacuse if you not stored any values for that key it will return as false.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best choice would be to just use SharedPreferences. SharedPreferences let you easily save values. For example:

When you press a button

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
prefs.edit().putBoolean("button_1_pressed", true).apply();
```

When you start your activity. I.e (OnCreate())

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
boolean isButtonPressed = prefs.getBoolean("button_1_pressed", false);
if (isButtonPressed) {
// TODO make button green
}
```